# Python 3 - Cannot make relative imports to flask server application created in virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, python-import

I set the `FLASK_APP` to `api.py` and then run `flask run`, but then 
I receive the error `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` . There's no error on PyCharm whatsoever, which confirms that syntactically this is correct.

**api.pi**

```
from . import models 
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, Welcome to the API!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**The directory structure**

```
           ├── ProjectDirectory
           │    ├── flask-api
           │    │   ├── venv
           │    │   ├── api.py
           │    │   └── models.py
           │    ├── modelpackage
           │    │   ├── __init__.py
           │    │   ├── classA.py
           │    │   ├── classB.py
           │    │   ├── helpers.py
           │    │   └── simplescript.py
```

As you can see above, both `api.py` and `models.py` are in the same directory, and using the `from . import models` line should import the script's code into `api.py` . For reference, this flask server was made using `virtualenv`, following the official Flask docs, hence there is a `venv` directory in the `flask-api` directory.

Also, `models.py` further imports stuff from the `modelpackage`, so that's why I included it above for completeness.

Does this have something to do with Flask/VirtualEnv/Directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When module is used as main its name is `__main__` . And so relative imports do not work. You should use absolute imports.
i.e
`from flask_api import models`

Here is link for more info [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "**main**", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.

**Note:** According to PEP8 use absolute imports rather than relative ones.

Comment: actually I realised from your answer that I forgot to add an `__init__.py`

Comment: Yes. that would work but not when current module's name is `__main__`